# creating a dynamic textarea in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic textarea but I don't know how fix the keyup operation so the resize function would work only when a /n exist

script:

```
function ResizeTextArea() {

        var msgTxtHeight = $("#<%=Message_txt.ClientID %>").css("height");

        var containerDivHeight = $(".MsgDiv").css("max-height");


        if ($("#<%=Message_txt.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            $("#<%=ConversationDIv.ClientID %>").css("height", "318px");
            $("#<%=Message_txt.ClientID %>").css("height","15px");
        }
         if (msgTxtHeight >= containerDivHeight) { return false; }
          $("#<%=Message_txt.ClientID %>").css("height", $("#<%=Message_txt.ClientID  %>").height() + 15);
           $("#<%=ConversationDIv.ClientID %>").height($("#<%=ConversationDIv.ClientID %>").height() - 15);

    }
```

html:

```
  <div id="ConversationDIv" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="height: 318px;
    width: 100%; overflow: auto;" class='convoDiv'>
</div>
<table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="width: 91%">
        <div class="MsgDiv">
          <asp:TextBox ID="Message_txt" runat="server" Width="100%"   TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="Messagetxt" onkeyup="ResizeTextArea();"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
        </td>
     </tr></table>
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/49HQM/195/

Comment: That looks a bit like a mess, mixing code like that... Why not just create an object in ASP? Then echo it out as a JSON object on the global JavaScript scope, so you can use it throughout the code.

Comment: @TusharGupta us didn't change anything

Comment: As per your code, the textarea max-height will be less than or equal to your div - MsgDiv.

Comment: you didn't understand my problem i guess i didn't explain much my problem is that i want to know when a '\n' is detected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/49HQM/197/)

```
$("#Message_txt").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            ResizeTextArea();
        }
    });
```

[e.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

updated after op's comment

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/49HQM/198/)

```
    function isOverflowed(element) {
        return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight || element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;
    }
 $("#Message_txt").keyup(function (e) {
        if (isOverflowed(this)) {
            ResizeTextArea();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i can't use this code bcs i don't want to trigger it when the user hits enter i want to detected dynamically when a character reached the end of the textarea there when a /n is detected